# Automatically add all files from folder as embedded resource

Tags: c#, msbuild

1. We wrote small app in `C#`. It is "installer" that copy files - embedded resources - to some location.
2. We created one batch file which copies latest versions of these files and build the solution using `msbuild.exe`.

The problem here is that if anyone want to add another file (or remove existing file) they have to do it manually through Visual Studio.
Is there some way how one can do this automatically?

**Example:**
I have folder `embeddedResources` and in there I have files `a.txt` and `b.txt`. Both set as Embedded resources. Is there some automatic way, how to add new file `c.txt` as Embedded resource if I copy it to the folder `embeddedResources`? Or how to successfully build the solution if I delete the file `a.txt`?

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171453.aspx#BKMK_Wildcards the section on "Using Wildcards to Specify Items". You just need to specify a wildcard for the EmbeddedResource.Include item in your csproj file.

Comment: @Kevin yes, this is the solution. Thank you for your quick help.

Answer (score 2):

Just add following ItemGroup into your `.csproj`:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="embeddedResources/*.txt" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Every file in `embeddedResources` folder with `.txt` extension will be automatically set as embedded resource.